# Giving a user a discount based on their email address?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function updatePrice() {
  var price = document.getElementById("product").value;
  var size_price = document.getElementById("size").value;

  var a=parseInt(price);//parsed type price
  var b=parseInt(size_price);//parsed size price

  if(size_price != "null")//if the value selected is not null then add the prize
  {
        var fin_price = a+b; //add the prices
  }
  else //if the value selected is null then fin_prize=price 
  { 
       var fin_price = price;    
  }
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="<p> <mark> PRICE: € " + fin_price + " </mark></p>";
}
</script>

<form  method="post"  action="http://atlantis.cit.ie/displayvalues.php" form onsubmit='return phoneValidation(),validateCard(this),euroValidation()'>  

<h2>Order Form</h2>
<label >Shirt Type</label>

<body onload="updatePrice()">
    <select id="product" onchange="updatePrice()">
         <option id="basic" value="20.00"> Basic Shirt (€20.00)</option>
         <option id="poly" value="25.00">Poly-Cotton Blend (€25.00)</option>
         <option id="gildan" value="28.00">Gildan Cotton (€28.00)</option>
         <option id="organic" value="30.00">Organic Cotton (€30.00)</option>
    </select>

    <br>

     <label >Shirt Size</label>

     <select id="size"  onchange="updatePrice()">
         <option id="None" value="null">Choose Size</option>
         <option id="Small" value="0.00" value= "Small">Small</option>
         <option id="Medium" value="0.00" value= "Medium">Medium</option>
         <option id ="Large" value="0.00" >Large</option>
         <option id ="XL" value="0.00">XL</option>
         <option id ="XXL"value= "2.00">XXL (+€2)</option>
         <option id ="XXXL" value="3.00">XXXL (+€3)</option>
     </select>

     <br>



                <label >Character</label>

                <select id="character" name='character'>
                <option value="None">Choose Character</option>
                <option value="Sonic">Sonic</option>
                <option value="Drake">Drake</option>
                <option value="Joel">Joel</option>
                <option value="GTA">Grand Theft Auto</option>
                <option value="Mario">Mario</option>
                <option value="Ezio">Ezio</option>
                </select>
                <br/>

                <label >Shirt Colour</label>

                <select id="colour"  required name='colour'>
                <option value="None">Choose Colour</option>
                <option value="Red">Red</option>
                <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
                <option value="Blue">Blue</option>


               </select>

                <div id="price"><p><mark>PRICE: €XX.XX</mark></p></div>

                <br/>


<label>Name:</label>
<input id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Name" type="text" autofocus > <br>
Address:
<br>
<TEXTAREA NAME="address" 
  required ROWS="3" COLS="25">
</TEXTAREA> <br>
<label>Email:</label>
<input id="email" name="email"  required placeholder="Email" type="text"> <br>
<label>Sex:</label>
<input id="male" name="sex" required type="radio" value="Male"> 
<label>Male</label>
<input id="female" name="sex" type="radio" value="Female"> 
<label>Female</label> <br>
<label>Phone No:</label> 
<input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile No." type="text">  <br>
<label>EBNS:</label>
<input id="EBNS" name="EBNS" placeholder="EBNS No." type="text"> <br>
<label>Card No:</label>
<input id="cardno" name="cardno" placeholder="Card No." type="text"> <br> 
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now">
</form>
```

I have this function that determines the price of a product but I also need to offer a discount based on the persons email address if it contains certain characters but I can't get my head around it. I tried doing something like the code below but it didn't work, can anyone shed some light on this please?

```
    if (validEmail.indexOf("@mycit.ie") > -1) {

    {discount = .10}

     totalCost=totalCost*discount;

    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="<p> <mark> PRICE: € " + totalCost + " </mark></p>";


    } else {

        totalCost=totalCost
    }
}
```

Comment: `else { totalCost=totalCost }` does nothing. Also, where is `totalCost` declared?

Comment: Client-side looks like an awful place to perform that check -- I can easily inject a new value for your `validEmail` variable so I always get a discount. **This is a job for the server, not the client.**

Comment: Was just typing the same @FrédéricHamidi!

Comment: I know that but in this case this is the way I have to do it for the moment

Answer (score 0):

To get the totalCost and not only the amount of the discount you would need to use

```
totalCost=totalCost - (totalCost*discount)
```

also be sure that your block is run after the one that sets the fin_price in the same element (price)

Comment: there is too much we do not see, where is your discount calculation located, what is exact the problem (wrong number, no discount at all, js error?), where are the variables defined you use....

Comment: ideally I want to integrate the discount in the update price function but i'm not sure how to integrate it without messing up the price I know i have to use the index of part but I'm not sure after that

Comment: Stumped on this just going to have to leave it out